# multiply matrix with scalar

Tags: python

i need to create a function that multiply matrix with scalar without using numpy. tthe problem here is that the function doesn't return a matrix.( so for the matrix below it needs to return [[2,4],[6,9.0],[10,84]]

```
def mul_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):

           # Write the rest of the code for question 5 below here.

    mat_new = []

    for j in mat:

        for i in j:

            a = (i* alpha)

            mat_new.append(a)

            continue

    return mat_new  

print mul_mat_by_scalar([[1,2], [3,4.5], [5,42]], 2)
```

Comment: I don't think your question shows enough research effort... Can you for instance write the (mathematical) definition of scalar matrix multiplication for us?

Comment: And you can also talke a close llok at your variables. What is the type of `a` ? what does the your `append` do ?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use a list comprehension like this:

```
def mul_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):
    return [[alpha*j for j in i] for i in mat]
```

It just multiplies every element in `mat` by `alpha` and returns the new matrix.

For your approach to work, you would have to append lists and not just `a`. You would write something like this:

```
def mul_mat_by_scalar(mat, alpha):

           # Write the rest of the code for question 5 below here.

    mat_new = []
    for j in mat:     
        sub_mat=[]
        for i in j:
            a = i* alpha
            sub_mat.append(a)
        mat_new.append(sub_mat)

    return mat_new
```

But that is ugly and not pythonic